# is it possible to get file properties

Tags: 2010, development, client-object-model

I'm trying to crawl over site documents and find their properties. 
While I was able to do the first part, using something like

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http:xxx");
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...);
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(oWebsite);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        List tlist = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
        clientContext.Load(tlist);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = tlist.GetItems(query);
        clientContext.Load(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (ListItem item in items)
        {
          ... do something with item.File...
        }
```

I could not find a way to get to the file properties, something which is possible with SharePoint Server, e.g.

```
SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Documents"];
foreach (SPListItem item in lib.Items)
{
  if (item.File.Properties.Contains("_Comments"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("File {0} contains comment {1}.", 
      item.File.Name, item.File.Properties["_Comments"]);
  }
 }
```

Is there any way to do this, without actually copying the file from the SharePoint?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fetch the properties explicitly:

```
clientContext.Load(
                items,
                lstitems => lstitems.Include(
                item => item["_Comments"],
             ));
```

Comment: Hm, it does not work for me either: I used this code `CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            ListItemCollection items = tlist.GetItems( query );
            clientContext.Load(items  , lstitems => lstitems.Include(
                item => item["_Comments"]
                
             ));` but I'm always getting the following exception : Column 'Comments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /DEV/DEV1/Shared Documents

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clientContext.Load(items, 'Include(_Comments)');
```

instead of

```
clientContext.Load(items);
```

Comment: That's actually the code for the JavaScript Client Object Model. @Igor you will have to use Linq when working with the .net client object model. (I am adding the code in an answer below due the lack of formatting in comments)

Comment: Oops, didn't notice it was .NET. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your foreach loop, you need to load each file.

```
   clientContext.Load(item.File);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   if (item.File.Properties.Contains("_Comments"))
   { 
     Console.WriteLine("File {0} contains comment {1}.", 
     item.File.Name, item.File.Properties["_Comments"]);
   }
```

Cheers !